# kindly suggest the mistake in following code?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

```
#include<iostream.h>
template<class T>
class myclass;

template<class T>
void f(myclass<T> &c);

template<class T>
class myclass
{
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        friend void f(myclass<T> &c);

    T getvalue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    void setvalue(T v)
    {
        value=v;
    }
};

template<class T>
void f(myclass<T> &c)
{
    cout<<endl<<"function called:\n";
    cout<<c.getvalue()<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    myclass<int> object;
    object.setvalue(6);
    f(object);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is regarding templates with friend functions. While running the code, I am getting the following error:

> error:undefined reference to f(myclass &) in line 22

kindly suggest. thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a comment where line 22 is?

Comment: _`#include<iostream.h>`_ Are you trying this with Turbo C++?

Comment: c free....i am working with.....it was value=v; but it is solved now..thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the friend function like

```
friend void f<>(myclass<T> &c);
```

Also in "new" C++ header iostream shall be specified like

```
#include <iostream>
```

and you should use directive

```
using namespace std;
```

if you do not want to change the other code in the program.

Comment: hey thanks...dis too worked.....but this compiler works with old syntax of header file.....so second suggestion wont work with it

Comment: @neha It seems your old compiler does not support namespace names.:)

Answer (score 0):

You missed to specify the template in the `friend` declaration:

```
template<typename U>
friend void f(myclass<U> &c);
```

See a fully working [sample](http://ideone.com/9udnET) here please.

Comment: but why is it required to specify different template argument U when we have used T in forward declaration....when we use T it shows error...why so?

Comment: @neha _"when we use T it shows error...why so? "_ Because `T` is already used by the enclosing template class.